# Plesk unable to send mail with external mx

Tags: email, dns, web-hosting, spf

In my Onyx OVH plesk server, I disabled the mail service on my domain, dcid-web.com, to use ovh mx servers.

I configured the DNS zone with the ovh mx.

I have no problem with sending and receiving mail with my client mail for this domain from my PC, but the website (wordpress) can't send mail.

No error is returned

I have tried to send mail with a test script including php mail function, same problem.
OVH support redirect me to the ovh forum, but any response to my answer...

My spf record :

```
"v=spf1 a mx ~all"
```

The test script :

```
<?php
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
$from = "admin@dcid-web.com";
$to = "xxxx@gmail.com";
$subject = "Vérification PHP mail";
$message = "PHP mail marche";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
echo "L'email a été envoyé.";
?>
```

Here is the log of the mail server, it looks ok :

```
Mar 27 16:20:05 ns3082437 check-quota[11312]: Starting the check-quota filter...
Mar 27 16:20:05 ns3082437 journal: plesk sendmail[11311]: handlers_stderr: SKIP
Mar 27 16:20:05 ns3082437 journal: plesk sendmail[11311]: SKIP during call 'check-quota' handler
Mar 27 16:20:05 ns3082437 postfix/pickup[2605]: DF28A3CC05C9: uid=10013 from=<xxxx@dcid-web.com>
Mar 27 16:20:05 ns3082437 postfix/cleanup[11318]: DF28A3CC05C9: message-id=<20190327152005.DF28A3CC05C9@ns3082437.ip-145-239-67.eu>
Mar 27 16:20:05 ns3082437 postfix/qmgr[32578]: DF28A3CC05C9: from=<xxxx@dcid-web.com>, size=388, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 27 16:20:06 ns3082437 postfix/smtp[11322]: DF28A3CC05C9: to=<xxxx@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.167.26]:25, delay=0.9, delays=0.17/0/0.18/0.54, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1553700006 z131si133565wmb.168 - gsmtp)
Mar 27 16:20:06 ns3082437 postfix/qmgr[32578]: DF28A3CC05C9: removed
```

Actually i can't receive messages from my contact form, really boring !

Comment: Check your mail server logs.

Comment: Mails servers are hosted by ovh

Comment: If you're using `mail()`, you're sending through localhost.

Comment: Yes, thank's you're right, i add the server logs

Comment: That does indeed say it delivered the message successfully- check your spam folder.

Comment: Oh sorry, you're right the mails are in spam folder ! thanks

Comment: Well the problem is not at your end - your script’s involvement ends after delivery.

Comment: But why the mails is in spam box when sended by my server and not when i send them by my mail client ?

Comment: I don't know - but take a look at the message headers as they will often contain info about why. Gmail's spam filtering is terrible.